# Extract fixed-position substrings from file

Tags: regex, bash, awk, cat

I need to extract substrings from a file into a new file.  Mac or Linux.

The data is between the 4th and 5th "|" symbol.

```
HD|262339|9400530374||K7UKD|A|HA|12/15/2009|03/13/2020
```

The actual columnar position varies, sometimes by a lot, but the data is always between the 4th and 5th pipe symbol.

Sample data is as above, expected output would be `K7UKD`.

I've tried various hacks at a regex:

```
grep  "/\|(\w+)\|/" input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: One attempt added to question along with expected output. Sample input was in the original question.

Comment: Try: `awk -F'|' '{print $5}' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

There are 2 ways to get it:

Any awk version:

```
awk -F'|' '{print $5}' file

K7UKD
```

or using `gnu-awk`:

```
awk -v RS='|' 'NR == 5' file
```

---

Here is a `bash` solution using `read`:

```sh
IFS='|' read -ra arr <<< 'HD|262339|9400530374||K7UKD|A|HA|12/15/2009|03/13/2020' &&
echo "${arr[4]}"

K7UKD
```

Or using `cut`:

```
cut -d'|' -f5 file
```

Or using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^([^|]*\|){3}\|([^|]*).*/\2/' file
```